# attic flooring above garage

Tags: attic, storage, decking, attic-conversion

I'm planning to have simple storage on the attic above the garage.
The size of beam I measured is 2x6 and around 11 inches apart. I will only work on the 2/3 of space to avoid the area with wires.

I'm wondering, for storage purposes...

1. What size plywood should I use?
2. Can I just set them on the beam without nailing them in?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add some pictures and a little more about what you want to do.  Sometimes people say "garage attic" when what they have is just rafter ties that are too long to support weight or a truss roof that is not designed to support weight from its bottom sections.    Sometimes people say "storage" and mean light weight shelves to store light items, or they might want to walk around on it.  More description would help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is my attic floor over my garage strong enough to use it for storage and maybe as a small work area?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/55306/is-my-attic-floor-over-my-garage-strong-enough-to-use-it-for-storage-and-maybe-a)

Comment: Or this? [Is it safe to add a floor to my garage attic?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/195227/is-it-safe-to-add-a-floor-to-my-garage-attic)

Comment: Or this? [Using Attic/Loft Space Above Garage for Storage - Adding a Subfloor](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/121790/using-attic-loft-space-above-garage-for-storage-adding-a-subfloor)

Comment: Or this? [Add storage to hidden attic space above garage?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/190178/add-storage-to-hidden-attic-space-above-garage)

Comment: Or this? [How to build attic space in garage](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/81208/how-to-build-attic-space-in-garage)

Comment: Or this? [Okay to cover attic joists with plywood?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/227959/okay-to-cover-attic-joists-with-plywood)

Answer (score 2):

First, you should determine if your garage structure can support storage at all. The length of those 2x6 that are 11 inches apart (odd spacing, if accurate) will matter quite a bit in that. Or the drawings for your garage when it was built will actually tell you explicitly. 12 inches on center would have space between the joist faces of 10.5 inches, which would be "around 11" but also a more normal joist spacing...

For 1, normally whatever the stock size plywood sheet in your part of the world is - 4 feet by 8 feet is normal where I am. Sometimes for attic projects they need to be cut smaller to get them into place.

As for 2, you'll regret that when one slides off the joist and you step on it, it tips, and you fall either until you hang up on the joists yourself, or all the way to the floor below.

Comment: You only do 2 once.  You make sure the nails are in after.